# Questions about C++ GUI project types and controls

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc

I like C++, and I have used GUI many times in C#, but this time I would like to make a GUI in C++. I already know the basics of the Win32 API, such as creating a window, resource scripts, commands and processing of commands, and the basics of some controls.
 
But what I would like to know, is how to choose between pure Win32 API or MFC to make applications with sidebars that can be disconnected and connected from the window just by clicking and pulling, as the image below:

[image: Sidebar in question]

And the other type of control I'd like to know, is what kind of list is this in red in the image below?  In the bottom circled, I know it's a mix of tree view with that kind of list. I thought it was a table control or similar, but it is not.

[image: List I want to know what kind of control is]

Anyway, I must continue studying pure Win32 API, or should I jump directly to MFC? I do not intend to use .NET or C#, only pure C++ with some libs.

Comment: It is usually called a "TreeList".  Not a standard control but commonly sold by component vendors.  It will be a while before you know enough to create one yourself, be sure to take the time.

Comment: The same effect can be achieved in pure Win32 using an owner-drawn List view in report mode.

Comment: Ok but, and the sidebar that can be dragged, what's the name of this component, I'm looking at the wxWidgets suggested by the person below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a look at more modern C++ gui frameworks, like Qt.

If you want to learn more about Windows, you can use either Winapi or MFC. //MFC is just a pretty thin (and oop) layer over Winapi.

QBittorrent is using [Qt framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html), so those are most likely a [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html)/[QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) and [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html)/[QTreeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html).

Comment: You might consider wxWidgets as well.  Its structure is very similar to MFC, but it doesn't require dialog resources.

Comment: @DanKorn: MFC doesn't require dialog resources either. It just makes creating dialogs using a scripting language and visual editor a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks man I took a look at qt and it seems to be interesting, however as it is paid I'm taking a look at wxWidgets

Comment: Qt is open source (lgpl license), the commercial is only one option.